# SQL syntax error ranking scores in LeetCode

Tags: mysql

I'd like to solve this LeetCode problem, https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores/, using MySQL following this example in the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank):

```
SELECT score, RANK() OVER w as 'rank'
FROM scores
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY score DESC);
```

I've created a test database (using the Django ORM) in which this works fine:

```
mysql> SELECT score, RANK() OVER w as 'rank' FROM scores WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY score DESC);
+-------+------+
| score | rank |
+-------+------+
|  4.00 |    1 |
|  4.00 |    1 |
|  3.85 |    3 |
|  3.65 |    4 |
|  3.65 |    4 |
|  3.50 |    6 |
+-------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, if I enter this in LeetCode I get a syntax error:

[image]

Any idea what the problem is here? Perhaps `RANK()` is a new function which the MySQL version on LeetCode doesn't have yet?

Comment: What exactly is the syntax error?

Comment: Click on the "*i*" left of "MySQL" in that dropdown and you'll get "Run with mysql-server 5.7.21.". MySQL 5.7 does not support window functions. Try with another DBMS (but you'd likely need to change that `'rank'` alias to either not use quotes or double quotes -- the proper way to enclose identifiers is in SQL) or change your query not to use window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Rank Is not supported in MySql 5.7.21 . Only from Mysql 8 , we can use rank function, you can try the below query

`SELECT Score,
  (SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT distinct Score s FROM Scores) tmp WHERE s >= Score) 'rank'
FROM Scores
ORDER BY Score desc`